# Is there a way to calculate backwards how many times a condition has happened?

Tags: pine-script

The function `cum()` does what the title says but it calculates in a forward movement. As condition happens it will sum it to the previous total.

eg. If I wanna know how many times close > open I could simply use the formula `BarUP = cum(close > open ? 1 : 0)` and it will calculate how many times this happened from the first candle

But is there a way to calculate how many times that happened only from the bar when another condition happened? eg. since the previous times rsi crossed below 30?

In the picture below it shows a bit clearer what I mean. I'd like to be able to check how many times the condition was true since each occurrence. I was considering counting from the index of the bar when each occurrence happened, but `bar_index` works only on the current real time candle, not the candle that the script is calculating.

[image: example]

Using a `for` loop as the example below, it would work but, if there were to be multiple times that rsi<30, the formula would calculate only the occurrences between the 2 conditions and the loop might run a very high number of times, making the formula take too long to calculate when incorporated into a longer script.

```
int tot = na
for i = 0 to barssince(rsi<30)
    if close[i] > open[i]
        tot += 1
```

In a few words, I'm basically looking for something that could replicate `cum(x, length)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a var declared integer to store the count for events given your conditions. To either reset the count or to add to the count.

```
//@version=5
indicator("RSI30", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

var int bull_count = na
bull_bar = close > open


rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

if rsi < 30 and rsi[1] >= 30
    if bull_bar
        bull_count := 1
    else
        bull_count := 0
else if rsi < 30 and rsi[1] < 30
    if bull_bar
        bull_count += 1

if rsi < 30 and bull_bar
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = low, text = str.tostring(bull_count), style = label.style_label_up, size = size.tiny, color = color.lime, textcolor = color.black)

bgcolor(rsi < 30 ? color.new(color.red, 70) : #00000000)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but I guess my question wasn't formulated in the best way. I've modified the question adding a picture to maybe make it clearer what I mean. The ideal would be if there would be a way to code `if indexbar == indexbarconditiontrue` `iff(bull_bar, 1, 0)` `else` `if bull_bar` `bull_count += 1`

Answer (score 0):

count(cond, len) =>
math.sum(cond ? 1 : 0, len)

countSince= count(yourCondition,100)

plot(countSince)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).